# trouble finding max value from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

*edit: I'm using sqlite3

I have a database with 3 tables; pc, laptop and printer. They have, among others, the columns model and price. I'm trying to select just the model of the highest price from any of the tables. My attempts have lead me to:

```
select model
from
    (select model, max(price)
     from 
        (select model, price
         from laptop
         union all
         select model, price
         from printer
         union all
         select model, price
         from pc));
```

which gives me the last model from all the tables. However if I do:

```
select model, p
from
    (select model, max(price) as p
     from 
        (select model, price
         from laptop
         union all
         select model, price
         from printer
         union all
         select model, price
         from pc));
```

it gives me the correct result but I'm stuck with the price as well. I don't understand how this is possible.

Comment: What database are you using? (mysql, oracle, sql server, etc.)

Comment: Use `ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY price DESC` or whatever is equivalent in your RDBMS.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I'm using sqlite.

Comment: This bug has been [fixed](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/0bdf1a086b3946722f4d4b328e25917f61c14713) in version 3.8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, and will bring back ties as well:

```
select x.model
  from (select model, price
          from laptop
        union all
        select model, price
          from printer
        union all
        select model, price
          from pc) x
  join (select max(max_price) as max_price
          from (select max(price) as max_price
                  from laptop
                union all
                select max(price)
                  from printer
                union all
                select max(price)
                  from pc)) y
    on x.price = y.max_price
```